# Close ajax modal popup extender and open new from cs code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I am using ajax modal popup extender in `asp.net C#` web application. Simply After complete my process, I need to close the existing modal popup extender and open another modal popup extender and show logs into that. I need to do that things from `cs code` only. Anyone know how to do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate! Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299028/modalpopupextender-from-server-side-code-in-c-sharp

Comment: This might help as well: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Open-Show-ASPNet-AJAX-ModalPopupExtender-Modal-Popup-from-Code-Behind-Server-Side-in-ASPNet.aspx